# How to download only the latest file from SFTP server with Paramiko?

Tags: python, sftp, paramiko

I want to write script that connects to my university SFTP server and downloads the latest file with exercises. So far I've changed a little bit the code from Paramiko example, but I do not know how to download the latest file.

Here is my code :

```
import functools
import paramiko 

class AllowAnythingPolicy(paramiko.MissingHostKeyPolicy):
    def missing_host_key(self, client, hostname, key):
        return

adress = 'adress'
username = 'username'
password = 'password'

client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(AllowAnythingPolicy())
client.connect(adress, username= username, password=password)

def my_callback(filename, bytes_so_far, bytes_total):
    print ('Transfer of %r is in progress' % filename) 

sftp = client.open_sftp()
sftp.chdir('/directory/to/file')
for filename in sorted(sftp.listdir()):
    if filename.startswith('Temat'):
        callback_for_filename = functools.partial(my_callback, filename)
        sftp.get(filename, filename, callback=callback_for_filename)

client.close()
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use the [`SFTPClient.listdir_attr`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/sftp.html#paramiko.sftp_client.SFTPClient.listdir_attr) instead of the `SFTPClient.listdir` to get listing with attributes (including the file timestamp).

Then, find a file entry with the greatest [`.st_mtime` attribute](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/sftp.html#paramiko.sftp_attr.SFTPAttributes).

The code would be like:

```
latest = 0
latestfile = None

for fileattr in sftp.listdir_attr():
    if fileattr.filename.startswith('Temat') and fileattr.st_mtime > latest:
        latest = fileattr.st_mtime
        latestfile = fileattr.filename

if latestfile is not None:
    sftp.get(latestfile, latestfile)
```

---

For a more complex example, see [How to get the latest folder that contains a specific file of interest in Linux and download that file using Paramiko in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60218092/850848)

Comment: This has been of a great help Martin. Thanks!

Comment: After searching for hours online - this answer was perfect for my problem, Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
import paramiko
remote_path = '/tmp'

ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh_client.connect(hostname=<IP>, username=<USER>, password=<PW>,allow_agent=False)
sftp_client = ssh_client.open_sftp()

sftp_client.chdir(remote_path)
for f in sorted(sftp_client.listdir_attr(), key=lambda k: k.st_mtime, reverse=True):
    sftp_client.get(f.filename, f.filename)
    break

sftp_client.close()
ssh_client.close()
```

This will connect to the remote server (IP) using password (PW) as user (USER) & downloads the latest file available under <remote_path>

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: Updated and ftp_client was just a variable name, but renamed to stfp_client to avoid confusions, Cheers!