# How to add error handling with Python paramiko sftp on get filename with latest timestamp

Tags: python, sftp, paramiko

I have the below Python Paramiko SFTP script to download a file from SFTP where part of the filename is included and where file upload has the most recent timestamp (based on [How to download only the latest file from SFTP server with Paramiko?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30626615/850848)). However I am not sure how to go about adding error handling to the code:

```
RemotePath='/WM_Universe/out/'
RemoteFilename='EDI_CAB_Red_Part_'
LocalPath='O:/Datafeed/Debt/WMDaten/PoolFactor/In/'

#Create Date LongDate/ShortDate
date = datetime.date.today() 

ldate=(date.strftime ("%Y%m%d"))

latest = 0
latestfile = None

for fileattr in sftp.listdir_attr():

if fileattr.filename.startswith(RemoteFilename + ldate) and fileattr.st_mtime > latest:
    latest = fileattr.st_mtime
    latestfile = fileattr.filename

print (LocalPath + latestfile)

if latestfile is not None:
    sftp.get(latestfile, LocalPath + latestfile)
```

If the file is not available with the above name and having the most recent timestamp I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/username/PycharmProjects/SFTP.py", line 72, in <module>
    print (LocalPath + latestfile)
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str
```

I appreciate any help on implementing appropriate error handling for file availability/download successful or not. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Print the found file name, only if you actually find some:

```
if fileattr.filename.startswith(RemoteFilename + ldate) and fileattr.st_mtime > latest:
    latest = fileattr.st_mtime
    latestfile = fileattr.filename

if latestfile is not None:
    print (LocalPath + latestfile)
    sftp.get(latestfile, LocalPath + latestfile)  
else:
    print("No such file")
```