# Paramiko sftp.get failing to get file due to TypeError

Tags: python, sftp, paramiko

When trying to download files from `sftp` I connect to a folder via paramiko, in this folder, there are 4 files which I need to sort by time and download the latest 2. Using the `st_atime` attribute I can do this, however when trying to download the files using `sftp.get()` it is failing.

```
files = s.sftp.listdir_attr(path)
files.sort(key=lambda f: f.st_atime, reverse=True)
localpath = localdir + files
s.sftp.get(files[0], localpath)
```

Files will return 4 files in the format

```
file[0]
file[1]
file[2]
file[3]
```

When trying to download these using the `sftp.get()` it will return he following error:

```
raise TypeError("Expected unicode or bytes, got {!r}".format(s))
TypeError: Expected unicode or bytes, got SFTPAttributes: [ size=3017 uid=7129 gid=8001 mode=0100644 atime=1558001085 mtime=1558001084
```

After sorting the files do I need to convert them to a certain format in order to download them successfully

Answer (score 0):

file[0] is an Object, you have to put the filename instead :

```
s.sftp.get(files[0].filename, localpath)
```

See : [How to download only the latest file from SFTP server with Paramiko?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30626615/how-to-download-only-the-latest-file-from-sftp-server-with-paramiko)